# How to style/target a node that is created within a function, from outside of the function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to style (or change) div(s) created within a function. However, this "change" must not be made in the very same function. Given that variables created in functions is in the local scope of that function, how do I reach the created div(s) for later styling (or other changes for that matter) from outside? I have tried targeting the node with querySelector but Console returns Uncaught TypeError since it cannot find the variable.

Example code in JS:

```
let container = document.querySelector('.container');
let divClass = document.querySelector('.div-class');
divClass.style = "backgroundColor: green";

container.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let createdDiv = document.createElement('div');
    container.appendChild(createdDiv);
    createdDiv.classList.add('div-class');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you query before the element has even been created.

```js
let container = document.querySelector('.container');
    container.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let createdDiv = document.createElement('div');
        container.appendChild(createdDiv);
        createdDiv.classList.add('div-class');
    })
    
    let someButton= document.querySelector('.someButton');
    someButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        let divClass = document.querySelector('.div-class');
        divClass.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    })
```

```css
.container,.someButton{
  border:1px solid black;
  background:grey;
  margin-bottom:4em;
}

.div-class{
  height:40px;
  width:40px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  container
</div>


<div class="someButton">
  someButton
</div>
```

In this snippet, the access to the created div is put in another click event. If you click `.someButton` before `.container` it will create an error, but if you click after it will work since the div will be created.

Comment: How would this handle clicking `.someButton` before clicking `.container` for the first time, or provide access to multiple divs added by clicking the container? It may be worth considering the use of `cntainer.querySelectorAll` to check and/or access all the divs added...

Comment: As stated in the answer, clicking `.someButton` before `.container` will create an error. I did not want to change much of the original code to not "loose" OP. Just wanted to point out the source of the error they see. Without more context, we cannot really know if we should handle multiple elements or anything...

Comment: Thanks for the answer Salketer. With your code the styling doesn't take effect for me, although no error is seen in console log. I have experimented with this with multiple examples, but haven't been able to edit a an element created with createElement from the outside of the function in global scope or another local scope. Is this possible? How do you typically do these "createElement" cases when you want to apply styling in a later moment...?

Comment: I have added a working example. Check out where I style the element, I use the property backgroundColor from the style object.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a variable in global scope, and assign it the div which you create later.

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
// assign sample element to avoid error if new_div is used before assigning.
let newDiv = document.createElement('div'); 

container.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    container.appendChild(newDiv);
    newDiv.classList.add('div-class');
})

newDiv.style = "backgroundColor: green";
```